# puppeteer in docker behaves differently than the same puppeteer in local

Tags: javascript, docker, google-chrome, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to measure the width of an HTML element. I'm getting different values in local `puppeteer/chrome_headless` and docker  `puppeteer/chrome_headless`.

Steps to reproduce :

1) Open chrome console and paste the below code. It will give the width of the element.

```
    var elem = document.createElement('span')
    document.body.appendChild(elem)
    elem.innerHTML="text to be measured for width"
    elem.style.fontSize="20px"
    elem.style.fontFamily="serif"
    console.log(a.getBoundingClientRect().width)
```

2) Run the following command to run headless chrome in docker.

```
docker run -it --rm -p=0.0.0.0:9222:9222  --name=chrome-headless -v /tmp/chromedata/:/data alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk
```

3) Access headless chrome running in docker through any browser at `localhost:9222`. Click the link shown. Now paste the same code in the console. The width it is giving is different.

I need the headless browser in docker to give the same result as the local chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue is about measuring the appearance of an element, my bet is that the element in question is rendered differently between headless and non-headless browsers.

Try to explicitly set the dimensions of your viewport in Puppeteer and check that you are not using a different user agent (most likely you are using the same user agent).

```
//...
await page.setViewport({
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  deviceScaleFactor: 1,
});
//...
```

Comment: True, I found some website showed 10px offset difference on headless and headful version.

Comment: @Anas Tiour Tried setting viewport as you suggested. Same result again. And also I don't think the difference is between the headless and headful browser but between the browser in local and browser in docker

Comment: My next guess would then the base idocker image you are using: `alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk`. It seems from its Github repo that it uses the last  version of chrome (unstable). Could you please add details about the different versions of chrome you have?